# Filter a javascript array map by items in another array?

Tags: javascript

I have a component with an array of products that I am mapping through. In a different component, I have a list of checkboxes where the user can select any number of checkboxes which are prodict attributes. I am trying to create a filter for the map so that any products that have any of the checked attributes are displayed.

An example of the checkbox attributes would be:

```
  const attributes = [
    {
      firm: true,
      medium: true,
    },
  ];
```

So, out of all of the products, any that have an attribute of firm or medium would be displayed.

I have tried doing the following:

```
{data.products
  .filter((item) => item.categories.some(({ value }) => value === 'medium'))
  .map((item, id) => {
    return <ProductCard key={id} item={item} data={data} />;
  })
}
```

But that obviously only takes whatever value i hardcode in. I am not sure how to attempt this so that the filter will loop through any attributes in the `attributes` array.

Comment: Should `attributes` actually be an array?  It looks to me like a plain object would suffice.

Comment: yes, that is the format of it, it's something i am not able to alter

Comment: Does it have multiple entries, or will it always hold only one object?

Comment: it will on some occasions have other objects in it, just not ones that are pertinent to this filter

Comment: could you show sample data as text and desired output as text?

Answer (score 0):

Without some sample data, I'm not really sure if this does what you want, and I'm still a little fuzzy on the structure of `attributes`.  (You say there may be more than one element in the array, but others don't affect us.  Do we always take the first?  The last?  Something else?)

But this *might* do:

```js
const matchingAtts = (attributes, products) => {
  const atts = Object .keys (attributes)
  return products .filter (
    ({catetories}) => categories .some (({ value }) => atts .includes (value))
  )
}

// ...

{matchingAtts (attributes [0] /* ?? */, data .products)
  .map((item, id) => {
    return <ProductCard key={id} item={item} data={data} />;
  })
}
```

`matchingAtts` accepts an object formatted like the first entry of your sample `attributes` array and the list of products and returns an array of those have some categories whose `value`s are among the keys of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear by what properties you want to filter, however, if you have an array of checked properties and you want to filter by them, then you can filter it using `Object.values` method:

```
const shorterVersion = data.filter(f =>
  filterAttributes.some(s =>
      Object.keys(s).every(s => Object.values(f).some(v => v == s)))
)
```

An example:

```js
const filterAttributes = [
  {
    firm: true,
    medium: true,
  },
];

var data = [
  { name: "Joe", sign: '1', value: "small" },
  { name: "Mike", sign: 'firm', value: "medium" },
  { name: "Joe", sign: '2', value: "big" }
];

const result = data.filter(f => {
  return filterAttributes.some(s => {
    let attributeKeys = Object.keys(s);
    let dataValues = Object.values(f);
    let result = attributeKeys.every(s => dataValues.some(v => v == s));
    return result;
  })
})

const shorterVersion = data.filter(f =>
  filterAttributes.some(s =>
      Object.keys(s).every(s => Object.values(f).some(v => v == s)))
)


console.log(`result: `, result);
console.log(`shorterVersion: `, shorterVersion);
```

And this is more debuggable version:

```
const result = data.filter(f => {
  return filterAttributes.some(s => {
    let attributeKeys = Object.keys(s);
    let dataValues = Object.values(f);
    let result = attributeKeys.every(s => dataValues.some(v => v == s));
    return result;
  })
})
```